# Confused on step in proof of all partials existing in a neighborhood (and being continuous) implies differentiable at that point

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, manifolds

I'm reading Baby Rudin, and while proving that all partials existing in a neighborhood and being continuous, Rudin writes

> Suppose $h = \sum h_je_j$, $\vert h\vert < r$, put $v_o = \vec0,$ and $v_k = h_1e_1 + \ldots +h_ke_k$ for $1\leq k\leq n$. Then $$ f(x+h) - f(x) = \sum_{j=1}^n f(x + v_j) - f(x+v_{j-1}).$$

He then uses the mean value theorem.

> The mean value theorem shows that the $j$th summand is equal to
> $$h_j(D_jf)(x+v_{j-1} + \theta_jh_je_j).$$

This part is what confuses me. If the $j$th term is just $f(x+v_j) - f(x+v_{j-1})$, then wouldn't the MVT just imply that
$$
f(x+v_j) - f(x+v_{j-1}) = \theta_j(x+ v_j - x + v_{j-1}) = \theta_j(h_je_j) 
$$
where $\theta_j = D_jc$ for some $c$? Where do the other terms come from?

Comment: The way I read it, what you're calling $c$ is what Rudin calls $x + v_{j-1} + \theta_j h_j e_j$, and $(D_jf)(x + v_{j-1} + \theta_j h_j e_j)$ denotes evaluation, not a product. (The factor $h_j$ is the "length of the interval", $|v_j - v_{j-1}|$.)

Answer (score 2):

Given $1\leq j\leq n$, consider the one variable function
$$[0,1]\ni \theta\to F(\theta)=f(x+v_{j-1}+\theta h_je_j)$$
and apply the MVT with respect to the interval $[0,1]$. Then there exists $\theta_j\in (0,1)$ such that
$$F(1)-F(0)=F'(\theta_j)\cdot (1-0)$$
that is
$$f(x+v_{j})-f(x+v_{j-1})=D_j(f)(x+v_{j-1}+\theta_j h_je_j)\cdot h_j$$
because by the [multivariable chain rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule#Case_of_f(g1(x),_..._,_gk(x))),
$$F'(\theta)=\sum_{i=1}^n D_i(f)(g_1(\theta),\dots,g_n(\theta))\cdot g_i'(\theta)=D_j(f)(x+v_{j-1}+\theta h_je_j)\cdot h_j$$
where
$$g_i(\theta)=\begin{cases}
x_i+h_i  &\text{for $1\leq i<j$,}\\
x_j+\theta h_j  &\text{for $i=j$,}\\
x_i  &\text{for $j<i\leq n$.}
\end{cases}$$